# MacScript doesn't work in Normal.dtom in Mac Word - 2011

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I have few MacScripts.
1.

```
Dim folderLocation As String
folderLocation = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as string")  //return path of document folder
```

2.

```
Dim chkConnection As String
chkConnection = MacScript("do shell script ""curl  4 www.google.com""")   //check internet connection
```

Above MacScript work perfectly if I open document and add my add in from `Tools-->Templates and Add-ins`.
But If I copy my all functions in `Normal.dtom` (Purpose: it execute everytime when application starts), both of above script doesn't work.
First script throws error number '5' about Invalid procedure call or argument.
Second script return nothing.

Can you please suggest me solution of it?